# Update iPad 5th gen from 15.7.1 to 15.7.4

Tags: ipad, ipados, apple-configurator, mdm

For future debugging I want to keep one of our iPads 5th Gen (MP2F2FD/A) at a 15.7.x version, it currently has 15.7.1 installed.

With Apple Configurator 2 or via Finder there is only the "Newest" (right now: 16.4) option available. I tried to upgrade via our MDM to 15.7.4 but it's management history doesn't show any "Schedule OS Update" command as pending or finished.

The overview here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPadOS_version_history shows an 15.7.4 version, but https://ipsw.me/iPad6,11 doesn't show this version and shows the latest 15.7.x version as unsigned. So it seems that there is no signed version of 15.7.4.

Why is there no version 15.7.4 available for this iPad?

Comment: Your update now asks “why does/doesn’t  Apple do something” which is off topic. Apple doesn’t sign older releases of iOS.  This info is available in the linked dupe.

Comment: @Allan: Why is 15.7.4 old? It was released only some days ago. But I found an article saying that this update is only for devices that can't install i(Pad)OS 16. Which is odd because the previous update to 15.7.1 was available when iPadOS 16 was already available. I could not find an official Apple statement saying that capable devices can only upgrade to the newest eligible major version.

Comment: Also: Why is this off topic? I am here for "Answers for your Apple questions"...

Comment: Questions about why Apple does or doesn‘t do things the way they do are usually off-topic because any answer will be just a guess or an assumption. See also https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.